# jQuery $(document).ready half working (I think)

Tags: jquery, three.js, document-ready

I'm using this code

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('loaded');
    show();
});
```

so when everything on my page loads a function is run starting the project. However I'm using this with Three.JS where Im loading in models which are a few mb.

The script returns 'loaded' after a couple of milliseconds, however the models aren't completely loaded. In addition the Chrome console tells me that the models take a few seconds to completely load in :/

Is this the wrong way to go around it? Sorry I'm pretty new to it!

Comment: I don't know much about `three.js` but this isn't the "wrong" way to write something to the console once the DOM has loaded, and then calling another method. Are you getting any errors in your `three.js` code?

Comment: No errors in either jQuery or three.js :/ It is firing the code, just not when I was thinking it should

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The document is loaded.

three.js generates models which are not part of the initial document. They are inserted by ThreeJS when they've been generated as shown in the project page: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/

Notice the line:

```
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: Ah really? I see, its just weird because the models don't appear on the screen when its 'loaded'

Comment: The jQuery `ready` does not work for ThreeJS since ThreeJS generates DOM nodes itself. The ready event is just for the static HTML that the webserver returned.

Answer (score 1):

This page: http://lightmap.staticloud.com/ waits untill two textures are loaded and then shows the render button.

If think the source code of that sample page may help you.

```
var loadCount = 0;

function loadTexture(url) {
    var image = new Image();
    var texture = new THREE.Texture(image);
    image.onload = function() {
        texture.needsUpdate = true;
        console.log("texture " + url + " loaded");
        loadCount++;
        // Enable Render button when both images loaded
        if (loadCount == 2)
            document.getElementById("renderButton").disabled = false;
    };
    image.src = url;
    return texture;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery ready event will fire after the DOM has loaded. The window onload event will come later, after everything else (i.e. images, etc) have loaded.

Comment: Do you think its the three.js models, they're being loaded into the document via JSON, do you know if the jQuery ready would support this?

Answer (score 0):

The loadTexture function given above by Thdk is basically the same function given in the **[ImageUtils source](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/ImageUtils.js)** included in Three.js.

If you look at the source for the THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture function you can see it is identical to the one above except for some small changes. We have extra parameters for texture mapping and a callback as well. The callback is placed inside the Image objects onload event. This means we can utilize this to hold off on creating objects until we have their textures and making sure all of
them are loaded before we animate.

```
loadTexture: function ( path, mapping, callback ) {

        var image = new Image(), texture = new THREE.Texture( image, mapping );

        image.onload = function () { texture.needsUpdate = true; if ( callback ) callback( this ); };
        image.crossOrigin = this.crossOrigin;
        image.src = path;

        return texture;

    },
```

Using the callback you may utilize it in the following way to achieve what you want:

```
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(path1, null, function () {
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(path2, null, function () {
THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(path3, null, function () { renderingEnabled = true; }) }) });
```

Then surround the call to your animation logic and rendering call with an `if(renderingEnabled)`. Alternatively you could simply call the animation loop from the last callback if you set everything up properly.